# Connectedness and path connectedness in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: analysis, connectedness

My task is to show
$$
A = \{ (t, \sin(1/t)), t>0 \} \cup \{ (0,y), -1 \leq y \leq 1 \} \subset \mathbb
R^2
$$
is connected and is not path connected.

So far I realized that if it were path connected, then $A$ would be open and $A$ is not open (since the second set is closed). Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "if it were path-connected, then $A$ would be open". It is *not* true that path connected subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ are necessarily open. For instance, the graphic of any continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is always path connected and compact.

Comment: I see. I meant that because in class we proved that given $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, if $A$ is open then $A$ is connected iff $A$ is path connected.
So to be able to show $A$ is not path connected, we must show it is not open, right?

Comment: True; in this case $A$ is a closed subset with empty interior and, to be fair, the observation that it is the closure of the support of a curve is kind-of the starting point to prove it is connected.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the second set was closed. Why is the first one? Can I see it as a graph of the function y(x) = sin(1/x) which is closed?

Comment: That set is *not* closed. In fact, its closure is $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let \begin{align}A_+ &= \{(t,\sin(1/t):t>0\}\\ A_0 &= \{(0,y): -1\leqslant y\leqslant 1\}.\end{align}
$A_+$ is connected as the graph of a continuous function. If $-1\leqslant y\leqslant 1$, let $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $y=\sin\theta$. Then $y=\sin(\theta + 2n\pi)$ for all integers $n$, so if $t_n=1/\sin(\theta+2n\pi)$, then $\sin(1/t_n)=y$ for all $n$. Since $t_n\to0$, we have $$(t_n,\sin(1/t_n))\to(0,y),$$ so that $(0,y)$ is a limit point of $A_+$. It follows that $\overline A_+=A_+\cup A_0$ (as if $t_n\to t>0$ then $(t_n,\sin(1/t_n))\to(t,\sin(1/t))\in A_+$), and hence $A$ is connected as the closure of a connected set.

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to A$ is a path with $f(0)=(0,0)$ and $f(1)\in A_+$. Then $f^{-1}(A_0)$ is closed and has a maximum element $b$. Define $g:[0,1]\to A$ by $g(t) = f((1-t)b+t)$. Then $g(0) = S_0$ and $g((0,1])\subset A_+$. Since \begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{4n\pi+3\pi}2\right) &= -1, n\in\mathbb Z\\
\sin\left(\frac{4n\pi+\pi}2\right) &= 1, n\in\mathbb Z\\
\end{align}
for any positive integer $n$ we may choose $u_n>0$ with $u_n<\pi_1(g(1/n))$ and $\sin(1/u_n)=(-1)^n$. Since the projection map $\pi_1$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem implies that there exists $0<t_n<\frac1n$ such that $\pi_1(g(1/n))=u_n$. But $$g(t_n)=(u_n,\sin(u_n)) = (u_n,(-1)^n)$$ does not converge, as $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n = -1 \ne 1 = \limsup_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n,$$ while $t_n\to 0$. This contradicts the assumption that $g$ was continuous, and so we conclude that $A$ is not path-connected.

Comment: Wow, thanks. The maximum element $b$ you mentioned exists because $f^{-1} (A_0)$ is compact, right?

Comment: $A_0$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}(A_0)$ is closed (and necessarily compact as $[0,1]$ is compact).

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.